# Работа с методом

Tags: c#

Как правильно такое реализовывается или я что то не то себе надумал))) ?

Я хочу из метода вернуть в зависимости от ситуации, либо `string` - например `"error"` и закончить всё на этом,  либо экземпляр класса `HttpRequest` с которым дальше можно продолжить работать.

Спасибо!

Comment: Можете попробовать возвращать структуру где одно из полей будет Null а другое "error" или на оборот

Comment: Можно воспользоваться монадой [Result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGDo0gtWJ-Q).

Comment: Обьявляете что метод возвращает `object`, все обьекты можно кастить в `object`. `return (object)str;` либо `return (object)httpreq;` А после возврата прийдется разбирать обратно через `if (result is string)  Console.WriteLine((string)result)`.

Comment: С HttpRequest есть два прикола. Например, в случае ошибки 500 и т п, Response ловится через исключение. И второе - запросу после работы всегда надо делать close.

Comment: обычно делают класс типа `MyMethodResult` и добавляют в него нужные поля.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо - прям в этом же классе и создам поля, что то пытаюсь тут дома для себя ковырять, с ходу не додумался) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш способ влоб. Обьявляете что метод возвращает object, все обьекты можно кастить в object. return (object)str; либо return (object)httpreq;

```
object f(){
   ....
  return (string)"MyString";
  }


object result = f();
if (result  is string){
   Console.WriteLine((string)result)
 } else {
    ....
 }
```

Можно вернуть и строку и HttpRequest "одновременно", например так

```
 HttpRequest f(ref err){
     ...
     }
 ....
 string err;
 HttpRequest ret = f(ref err);
 if (ret == null) Console.WriteLine(err);
```

Вариант 3. Исключение.

```
HttpRequest f(){
    HttpRequest ret = null;
     ....
    if (ret == null) throw new Exception("Message");
   return ret;
   }

HttpRequest req = null;
try {
  req=f();
  } catch (Exception e){
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Этот способ "топорный". Я давал выше ссылку на монаду `Result<T>`, это более элегантный способ.